# Setting up mirroring in untrusted domain environment using Sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, mirroring, high-availability

I have setup mirroring only with principle and mirror in untrusted domain environment using certificates. I have successfully tested the mirroring session by doing a manual failover. But I see a lot of login failures in the mirror server saying

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'. Reason:
>   Failed to open the explicitly
>   specified database. [CLIENT: ]
>
> SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c, state 14 while
>   establishing a connection with
>   integrated security; the connection
>   has been closed. Reason:
>   AcceptSecurityContext failed. The
>   Windows error code indicates the cause
>   of failure.
>
> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
>   with Windows authentication.

I am not using windows authentication for mirroring. Can someone please suggest the way to avoid these errors from appearing in the error log. Also why is the principle server still trying to use windows authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those failures are not from the mirroring connection. Those errors are from your client trying to connect to the mirror instance.

The first error is from a local service that is attempting to open an explicit database that is offline (perhaps is trying to connect to the mirrored database). The second error is from a client that had failed the SSPI handshake. And the third one is from a client that has succeeded the hansdhake but is not trusted.

You have to verify your client apps connection strings and, your agent jobs etc etc and see who is attempting these connections.

Comment: I do not have any client applications accessing either principle or mirror servers. The second and third errors are because of the principle server trying to connect to the mirror server with windows authentication( At the end of the error messages it gave [CLIENT: "IP of principle server"]). Also why is NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE' trying to connect to mirrored database which is not accessible. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: You sure you do not have any SQL Agent job that is trying to connect to the database? BTW, I assume your DBM endpoints are configured to use certificates (as described here: http://rusanu.com/2008/10/23/how-does-certificate-based-authentication-work/)

Comment: Thanks Remus, The only Job running in sql agent is "Database Mirroring Monitor Job" and it is running successfully. I tried disabling analysis services and reporting services on mirror after which I don't see the first error anymore, but second and third errors are occurring repeatedly. Also the mirroring end points are configured correctly.

Comment: The point is that all those messages come from T-SQL clients, none is related to you DBM endpoints and the DBM session itself. DBM monitor job is also likely connecting to the mirror.

Comment: Thanks for helping me Remus, I could fix this issue. The DBM by default is trying to use windows authentication. It allows to change the authentication to SQL but it does not allow IP address in the server field, it accepts only "DomainName/ServerName". To fix it I had to unregister the databases in DBM and not use it, since we donot have a domain environment.

Comment: That is not true. DBM allows certificate based authentication, and allow DNS names instead of IP, neither requiring a domain.

Answer (score 1):

ok as follows: in the mirror monitoring tool you can set the connection / authentication it should use. Your probably best of removing the connections in the monitoring tool and reregistering them according to the accounts you have set in the endpoints.